# Peculiar Tcl syntax

Tags: tcl

I see the following in a Tcl script:

```
If { <some_condition> } {
  // code here...
} {
  // code here...
}
```

I am assuming this is a special case of `if-else` syntax? Would just like to get confirmation.

Comment: BTW  '//' does not start a comment in tcl. in fact it is a syntax error. Not to nitpick but other people might get wrong idea.  ... use # instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed just a variation on `if`-`else` syntax; the `else` is optional (as is the `then`, which virtually everyone omits but I like to use when I have a multi-line expression before it). It's usually a good idea to include it as that's less *visually* confusing, but you don't need it.

The only “keywords” in `if` syntax that are mandatory are `if` (you could `rename` that, but it would break all sorts of things) and `elseif` (for extra condition checks).

Comment: Always waiting for your authoritative answer when I have a Tcl question :P

Comment: @czchlong I do _not_ always have the answer! (And sometimes I've got to sleep or do work…)

Answer (score 3):

From the `if(n)` manpage:

> **if**  *expr1*  ?**then**?  *body1*  **elseif**  *expr2*  ?**then**? *body2* **elseif** ... ?**else**?
>          ?*bodyN*?

The `?else?`  is used in tcl documentation to indicate that an argument is optional.  Further on, it more explicitly says:

> The **then** and **else** arguments
>          are optional noise words to make the command easier to  read.